# "Opposite of (someone/something)" for "across from/opposite" in nonstandard colloquial prose

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage, colloquialisms

Consider the following quotes (emphasis mine).

> For a split second, I meet eyes with an older man standing in a still gaze just **opposite of** me amidst the sudden chaos. <sub>[source](http://www.epperlylegal.com/the-why/)</sub>

> Taking a seat on a stool just **opposite of** me, he gives me a huge smile. <sub>[source](http://www.mbreader.me/sides?page=0,7)</sub>

> Guards stood at my door and one sat just **opposite of** me, his eyes never leaving my face. <sub>[source (see page 39)](http://www.bookrix.com/book.html?bookID=stevie.grace_1357788083.5480129719)</sub>

> I was surprised when I caught sight of Alex, who was waiting just **opposite of** the bathrooms. <sub>[source](http://www.wattpad.com/14705105-coalesce-high-chapter-fifteen)</sub>

> They were standing just **opposite of** the road and looked hungry, so we picked some of the grass that was just out of their reach and feed them. <sub>[source](http://donaldweiting.com/main/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=105%3amy-proposal&catid=38%3astories&Itemid=56)</sub>

> There were two groups of people standing just **opposite of** each other. <sub>[source](http://books.google.com/books?id=cslLIOXx47kC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=%22standing+just+opposite+of%22&source=bl&ots=1asgwPszSm&sig=DZzFPZWR60tcydVgiqeand2xwU8&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=6yoOU5f8D-ie0wWFt4GwAg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22standing%20just%20opposite%20of%22&f=false)</sub>

These quotes are all using **opposite of** to mean "across from" or "opposite". Are these uses acceptable in formal English writing? Or do they imply a less formal register, i.e. are these meant to merely be reproductions of casual speech?

Please also consider this NGram: [source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sat+opposite+of%2Csat+opposite+you%2Csat+across+from+you%2Csat+opposite+us%2Csat+across+from+us&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csat%20opposite%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csat%20opposite%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csat%20across%20from%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csat%20opposite%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csat%20across%20from%20us%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I have not looked at all the links, but I would not use 'of' in any of the examples 1 to 6. I talk about 'the person who lives opposite me', but then I am British.

Comment: Aren't you confusing the construction 'cruel is the opposite of kind' with the prepositional phrase headed by _opposite_ ('the cafe is opposite the library')? There _are_ some compound prepositions ('Jane looked _out of_ the window', BrE especially; 'I don't have any pets, _outside of_ a couple of tarantulas').

Comment: FF shows that this use is obscure in written English. While it may be more common in spoken English, asking whether it sounds/feels right is probably too subjective for ELU.

Comment: @Bradd: That *specific* aspect of the question is effectively POB, but I disagree with the closevote (yours?) because I think there's an interesting backstory concerning the way the literal and figurative usages both started by using **to**, and have now diverged into one prepositionless and the other using **of**.

Comment: That's cool. It was a very borderline close vote for me. Probably wouldn't have even occurred to me except that I had just seen another question which is more blatantly POB in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say *opposite **of** me* is just plain ***wrong***. It has virtually no currency...

[image]

(If you click on the chart itself, you'll see that *opposite **of** me* doesn't occur enough to graph.)

---

I can only assume OP's citations involve people who are conflating two different usages...

> *[Jack Sprat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Sprat) sat opposite his wife...*
>
> *He is opposite her* (because he's on the other side of the table)
>    *He is **the** opposite **of** her* (because he will eat no fat, whereas she will eat no lean)

---

Centuries ago, *both* these senses were actually more likely to be expressed using the preposition **to**. [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sitting%20opposite%20me,sitting%20opposite%20to%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,sitting%20opposite%20me;,c0;.t1;,sitting%20opposite%20to%20me;,c0) shows how **to** has simply been discarded for OP's sense of *facing, on the other side*, and [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20opposite%20of%20this,the%20opposite%20to%20this&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,the%20opposite%20of%20this;,c0;.t1;,the%20opposite%20to%20this;,c0) shows how it's been replaced by **of** for the more figurative *complete contrast* sense.

Comment: Really? Then, you might just want to consider this other chart: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sat+opposite+you%2Csat+opposite+of%2Csitting+opposite+of%2Cwall+opposite+of%2Cseat+opposite+of%2Cchair+opposite+of&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csat%20opposite%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csat%20opposite%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csitting%20opposite%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwall%20opposite%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseat%20opposite%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchair%20opposite%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Nourished: Gimmie a break! You compared several unrelated text strings there, in such a way as to make *sat opposite you* appear to come at the bottom of a league table with *sat opposite of* on the top. If you [compare like with like](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sat+opposite+you%2Csat+opposite+of+you&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csat%20opposite%20you%3B%2Cc0) it's still the same as I've shown above - *sat opposite **of** you* is too uncommon to even chart against *sat opposite you*.

Comment: I didn't mean to be aggravating, FumbleFingers, I just wanted to demonstrate that "opposite of" does have some frequency (n AE at least), though admittedly to a less significant degree than "opposite". However, unlike you, I wouldn't say it's wrong, as long as some apparently articulate writers seem to prefer it to the standard, more common term.

Comment: @Nourished: I'm not going to go through them all with a fine toothcomb. But in the first of your links I found this just three sentences above your citation: *I look back to find a frenzy of movement – a panic-filled mad dash toward me and fast.* That's cut&pasted, so [sic]. I don't even think I can excuse that as any kind of typo - it's either a careless writer or not a very articulate one. And just glancing at the final paragraph, it really is nothing more than so much drivel. If you're happy with it then fine. I wouldn't give the guy a job requiring competence in writing.

Comment: Seems like you feign to not understand, FumbleFingers. I was not referring to the writers found through the links in the OP, but to those associated with my previous Ngram. That said, all of my examples in the OP come from native speakers that sound literate and fluent enough in their own language to be worth quoting...

Comment: @Nourished: I don't really understand where you're comming from with this. It's virtually inconceivable that there's even some *regional* dialect where *opposite of* is the normal usage. Certainly in the context of standard formal writing, it's "non-standard" - probably just carelessness or "illiteracy" rather than something that a "careful" writer would seriously defend. You seem intent on establishing that it's an "acceptable" usage, but, for example, I find just 17 instances of "sat opposite **of** them" in Google Books, compared to an estimated 29,200 hits for "sat opposite them".

Comment: ...Note that I only looked at "them" because that's the first "indirect object" I found when I drilled down into the results for your misleading NGram above. And I can't help noticing that *in the very same sentence*, the first cited result includes [Ms. Brown sat opposite Trent and next to Mr. Wynes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sat%20opposite%20of%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en). A writer who switches usages mid-sentence is not really to be trusted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13293/discussion-between-nourished-gourmet-and-fumblefingers)

Comment: It might just have to do with sonority and rhythm. To a writer's perspective, "opposite" followed directly by a pronoun -- e.g."She sat opposite me" -- might sound not rhythmical or melodious enough, or just not resonate with his or her style. And so, other phrases like the more widespread "across from" or the colloquial, disputed and nonstandard "opposite of" might just sound like better choices to his or her ear. It's all very subjective to a writer's preferences...